# Swift: How I can declare func in a protocol with return type self?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.2

I want to do something like this(this is not a compiled code, because this is just example what I want to receive in final):

```
protocol AP {
 class func perform() -> self
}

class A: UIViewController, AP {
//
...
//
 class func perform() -> A {
   return A()
 }
}
```

I need this as the result `let vc = A.perform()`, means that I need protocol that will be return self type of subscriber

How I can do it?

Comment: Your supplied code as it stands is invalid (it doesnt compile). What have you actually tried to do.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I know that it doesnt compile, it is just description what I need to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
protocol AP {
    associatedtype T

    static func perform() -> T
}

class A: UIViewController, AP {
    //
    ...
    //
    class func perform() -> A {
        return A()
    }
}
```

You can now do this as you wanted to:

```
let vc = A.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a static method and not a class method in your protocol.
2. Give a return type. Self is not a return type.

   ```
   protocol AP {
       func perform() -> ()
   }

   class A: UIViewController, AP {
       //
           ...
       //

       func perform() {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to achieve A.perform() not A().perform()

Comment: Then don't use protocol. Directly create a class method.

Comment: yes, but I want to specify some protocol and work through these protocol objects